# Dagger 2 injection fails due to class cast exception

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm using dagger for dependency injection and from time to time I get this class cast exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be   
           cast to myPackage.MyApplication                                                                              
       at myPackage.ui.activity.BaseActivity.injectAppComponent(BaseActivity.java:63)                                                                               
       at myPackage.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:42)
```

Here's my Base Activity method where I do the injection:

```
protected void injectAppComponent() {
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

Application Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private AppComponent appComponent;

private void injectComponent() {
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
    appComponent.inject(this);
}


public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return appComponent;
}
}
```

In my manifest, i define the app name like this:

```
application
    android:name="myPackage.MyApplication"
```

But I still experience this issue, any thoughts why this is happening?

Comment: Try adding `@Override public void onCreate() { super.onCreate(); injectComponent(); }` to your `MyApplication` class, otherwise this is supposed to work...

Comment: You inject appComponent only in Application class. Otherwise on other components you only add it as dependency.

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov how do I add them as a dependency?

Answer (score 3):

You probably aren't still looking for an answer, but I just ran into this issue and my problem was that **the interface of the class that I was trying to inject was package-private**.

I changed it to **public** and everything worked.